# Where is the buffer held when using curl_easy_pause

Tags: libcurl

When using the [curl_easy_pause](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_pause.html) while receiving data, is there a buffer in curl that will buffer the data is still received from the sender? Or is "pause" supported in the protocol?

Answer (score 3):

Pausing a curl transfer really means that curl will not read/write the data over the wire anymore, which effectively will make the transfer stop until the transfer is again resumed using the API.

While a download transfer is paused, curl will not read from the socket and thus not use any buffer. This uses normal TCP mechanisms that will stop the peer from sending data.

### HTTP/2 and HTTP/3

When stream-based protocols are used, like HTTP/2 and HTTP/3, libcurl will actually buffer up to a window-size number of bytes of data when the stream is paused since that is data "in transit" that libcurl needs to read before the transfers is effectively paused.

Comment: So in reality it is up to the hw to do the buffering?

Comment: @Daniel Stenberg, please tell me, but for example, if the client pauses, for example, for 100 hours - during this time, the server will not support the connection and will break it, after the client resumes transmission, an error will occur?